# Submit iOS apps update

Tags: ios

I am planning to do an apps update submission.

However, the new apps update need some data patching on server. I am unable to patch the data immediately, because the existing users with old apps will be facing issues with the new data.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: fetch data with version checking?

Comment: so do you means i export two different set of data according to version?

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain the old data almost indefinitely.

Plenty of users will not update their apps (no matter how much you want them to. ) for a large variety of reasons.

So for this time around you should move the new data to a different location (and reflect that new location in your app.) to ensure that old users maintain a connection to the old data and new users can use new data.

In the future it might be prudent to have your app stop to function when a new dataset and application is published and harass the user to update.

Comment: i will force user to perform apps update, which means i block them if they do not update the apps. I understand your point, but this is major update, so many data had to be change. I was wondering is there any better way for doing this.

Comment: The unfortunate catch-22 that you have is that you currently have users out there with a app which cannot be 'forced to update'

Comment: actually i can. I've apply something like CoC does. repeatedly prompt user for update, and do not allow them to login. Of cause this gonna make me lost some user.

Thank for the feed back. i asking this just to see whether there is better way of doing this.

Comment: @Steven this could only be done if the existing app has some knowledge about this. so CoC asks the server which version 'should' be running, and then harasses the user if they need to update.

Comment: yea. this feature has included in my apps when first launch.  Anyway, thank for the answer. i think i will apply dataset for different apps version.